# Uncaught Reference Error: Mosaic is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am interested in using this [MosaicJS plugin](https://jquery-mosaic.tin.cat/). The instructions seemed straight forward, so I tried to copy the basic implementation.

```js
$('#myMosaic').Mosaic();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mosaic/0.131/jquery.mosaic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mosaic/0.131/jquery.mosaic.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myMosaic">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/all" width="400" height="350" />
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/all" width="320" height="200" />
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/all" width="870" height="420" />
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/all" width="442" height="922" />
  </div>
```

When I did this, I get an error related to the JS script section:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Mosaic is not defined    at (index):131

Anyone else had this issue? I made a proper link to the actual jquery mosaic files in the HTML head section. What sort of solutions can be implemented? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your reference to `mosaic.js` is not throwing a 404 in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myMosaic').Mosaic();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just used the `jquery-mosaic` [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-mosaic).

```js
$('#myMosaic').Mosaic();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mosaic/0.131/jquery.mosaic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mosaic/0.131/jquery.mosaic.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myMosaic">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/all" width="400" height="350" />
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/450/all" width="320" height="200" />
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/900/800/all" width="870" height="420" />
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/all" width="442" height="922" />
  </div>
```